# Add new latitude longitude on google map like real-time tracking

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps

I am trying to display real-time tracking of order on google maps.
On first API hit, I am getting all data of tracking and successfully plotted on google maps.

Now I want to call API periodically (10 sec) and get new data for lat-long and add the only newly received lat-long in google maps.

It's like every 10 sec map will update and show the latest status of location - like real-time tracking.

Here is my JavaScript Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var latlongs = [];
    var orderID = "ASDF1234";


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.xyz.com/api/Order/PostOrderDetails',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify({ order_id: orderID }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

                $(data.data.latLong).each(function (index, orderData) {                    
                    var mylatlongs = new google.maps.LatLng(orderData.latitude, orderData.longitude);
                    latlongs.push(mylatlongs);
                });

                newlatlongsLength = latlongs.length;
                oldlatlongsLength = latlongs.length;


                var mapProp = {
                    zoom: 20,
                    center: latlongs[latlongs.length - 1],
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map-div'), mapProp);

                var trackPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: latlongs,
                    icons: [{
                        icon: {
                            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW
                        },
                        repeat: '175px'
                    }],
                    geodesic: true,
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });
                trackPath.setMap(map);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });          
    });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML Code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="google-map-div" style="height: 480px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Current View]

SO how can I call API in every 10 sec and plot update lat-long on google maps?

Answer (score 0):

you can use SetInterval For this scenario

First Create Function for your action. then you can call this function at setinterval..

```
      setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.xyz.com/api/Order/PostOrderDetails',
        dataType: "json",
        method: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify({ order_id: orderID }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            $(data.data.latLong).each(function (index, orderData) {                    
                var mylatlongs = new google.maps.LatLng(orderData.latitude, orderData.longitude);
                latlongs.push(mylatlongs);
            });

            newlatlongsLength = latlongs.length;
            oldlatlongsLength = latlongs.length;


            var mapProp = {
                zoom: 20,
                center: latlongs[latlongs.length - 1],
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map-div'), mapProp);

            var trackPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: latlongs,
                icons: [{
                    icon: {
                        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW
                    },
                    repeat: '175px'
                }],
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            trackPath.setMap(map);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });   },10000);
```

Comment: yeah setInterval is working for a periodic call. What about add new lat-long on google maps ?

Comment: Where do you get new lat long?

Comment: API call giving me new lat long. Our Android app adding new lat long in database. So i have to check API in every 10 sec. (API call gives me old data + new data all time)

Comment: So call the api from  setinterval in period of 10 sec ..
actually it gives updated lat long then you can try it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API will give you the full path on each call and that it won't mutate the previous points, you could grab the missing points and add them to the path via `trackPath.getPath().push`. Something like

```
var mapProp = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: latlongs[latlongs.length - 1],
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('google-map-div'), 
    mapProp
);

var trackPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    icons: [{
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW
        },
        repeat: '175px'
    }],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});
trackPath.setMap(map);

function update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.xyz.com/api/Order/PostOrderDetails',
        dataType: "json",
        method: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify({ order_id: orderID }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).then(function(data) {
        var path = trackPath.getPath(), 
            coords = data.data.latLong;

        // restrict the coordinates to the new values
        coords = coords.slice(path.getLength());

        // add each point to the path
        coords.forEach(function (od) {
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(od.latitude, od.longitude);
            path.push(point);
        });

        // sets a timer to update the points in 10 seconds
        setTimeout(update, 10000);
    });
}
update();
```

Note that the Polyline is created without any path and populated by the first call to `update`.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex for an example of points added to a path.

Comment: @Hardik Did that help? Or is there something that I missed?